# Ms Excel VBA - Using Shell command to open files

Tags: excel, vba

I am developing a workbook in Excel-VBA and i want to execute a script using HEC DSS. That means, using excel-vba, i need to open "HEC DSS" first and then i'll instruct the application to open the script.

We keep it simple and try to correlate the above scnerio with a NotePAd.exe and a txt file. For the purpose, i have googled and tried different things but none worked. I am trying to use the SHELL command. Please find the code below:

---

```
Sub test()

Dim retval as string

dim file name as variant

filename="C:\Users\Nayar Asif\Desktop\Test_2.txt"

retval = Shell("notepad.exe" & filename, vbnormalfocus)

end sub
```

The above code does not work. The idea is to open the notepad application and then open the notepad file. Any help????

Regards
Nayyar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

File paths with spaces should be in quotes

```
retval = Shell("notepad.exe """ & filename & """", vbnormalfocus)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Tim but i already have tried the command in this syntax.

Comment: Sub test()
Dim filepath As Variant
Dim retval As String
filepath = "C:\Users\Nayar Asif\Desktop\Test_2.txt"
retval = Shell("notepad.exe""" & filepath & """", vbNormalFocus)
End Sub. But it does not work. It gives the error "Rune-time error 53

Comment: That's not the same as my example: you have no space between `notepad.exe` and the file path

Comment: Yup. it worked. I was putting the "" in an incorrect way. Thank you very much TIm :)

Comment: I used this to first put the entire path to the OneNote.exe and then the file path to the file and worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

The solution is just the "space" after notepad.exe and before the second quote :

```
retval = Shell("notepad.exe " & filename, vbnormalfocus)
```